# How do you open a csv file on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, opencsv

I have downloaded a database from Kaggle (Video games with ratings) but I can't open it with my Jupyter Notebook.

I start with these 2 lines code but it gives me an error...

```
 import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv("Video_Game_Sales_with_Ratings.csv.xlsx")
```

---

> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import pandas as pd
>   ----> 2 df = pd.read_csv("Video_Game_Sales_with_Ratings.csv.xlsx")
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
>   usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
>   true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows,
>   na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines,
>   parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser,
>   dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal,
>   lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding,
>   dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter,
>   skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints,
>   use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
>       653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       654 
>   --> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       656 
>       657     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv("Video_Game_Sales_with_Ratings.csv")`

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for your quick reply @bhansa :) I did what you said but it gives me a new error : UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:14858)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:17119)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:17347)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8 (pandas\_libs\pars

Answer (score 1):

The file you are pointing at is an xlsx format. You need to save the file in csv format first and then import in into pandas. To convert xlxs to csv you can use excel or this applet:
http://www.zamzar.com/convert/xlsx-to-csv/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply !! :) I have changed the file in a csv format, but now it gives me another error : UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:14858)()

...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
pd.read_excel(file_name.xlsx)
```

Instead of turning your file into CSV, you can directly open the excel file in your previous format and even if it doesn't work try to look at the path of your file and make adjustments accordingly.

I hope this helps :)